# Is it possible to have spreadsheet behaviour for a table (grid of entries) in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, spreadsheet

I'm not very sure how to name the question and this may take some of your time, sorry for any inconvinience caused.
I have a matrix of calculation results (2d `numpy` array). 
I have a GUI in `tkinter`.
My purpose is to represent that results in a GUI table-like widget. In general it's no problem - I know I can use `tk.Treeview` or create a grid of `tk.Entries` and set their values by `insert()` method.

But there is one specific moment: I want rows and columns in that table-like widget be "copy-pasteable". Let me clarify: `tk.Treeview` is read-only, and when i create a net of `tk.Entry` widgets, user will be able to focus and copy the value of only one widget at a time.
So is it possible to get a behaviour close to Excel, when user can select and copy whole column or row?
Please correct me if I am unclear. Thanks in advance!